# Awaiting a non-async method

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm thoroughly confused by the whole await / async pattern in C#.

I have a forms app, and I want to call a method that takes 20 seconds to do a ton of processing. Therefore I want to `await` it. I thought the correct way was to mark it as `async Task` but doing this produces a warning because I don't use `await` anywhere within it.

A google revealed something about returning a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` but I don't have a return type, since it's void.

How can I call this method using `await`?

Comment: `async` does not execute the method on a background thread; I have an [`async`/`await` introduction](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that you may find helpful.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Call your method as following:

```
await Task.Run(() => YourMethod());
```

When you use the Task.Run method it creates an awaitable task for you.

Comment: Does Task.Run run "YourMethod" on the main UI thread, or creates a new thread? (e.g. WinForms)

Comment: @harag A little research would yeild (from MSDN in fact) that [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160373(v=vs.110).aspx) `Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool and returns a Task object that represents that work.`  So the answer is *most likely* (I believe it's definitely for WinForms).