# Tasks being run synchronous

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am currently trying to learn async-await in C# and run into the following problem:

I am building a server application that takes data from the database and runs calculations according the data it got. My current example is getting two dates wich I then get data for from different tables.

Because there is a lot of data I am accessing (about 10.000.000 entries per table) I wanted to speed things up by running each month (time frame given is usually one year) on multiple threads using async await.

The code in question looks something like this:

```
public async Task foo() {

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    for(int month = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        task.Add(this.RunJob(month));
    }

     await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private async Task RunJob(int month) {

    Console.WriteLine($"starting month {month}");

    //big calculation

    Console.WriteLine($"stopping month {month}");
}
```

But the code seems to run synchron because the console ends up displaying

```
starting month 0

stopping month 0

starting month 1

stopping month 1

...

starting month 11

stopping month 11
```

I currently don't see what mistake I am making as to my knowledge the code should run on multiple threads.

Comment: Well, do you *have* asynchronous code inside `RunJob`? Can you give example of one such piece of asynchronous code? Do you get a warning like "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously."?

Comment: Just so you know, tacking the keyword `async` onto a method does not magically make it run on a different thread. It means the compiler will allow you to use the `await` keyword inside, and the method will be rewritten to a state machine handling the interaction between tasks and the rest of the code.

Comment: First thing to keep in mind is that Async Await is not made for running on multiple threads. Async Await is made to more efficiently use a single thread, and if the async method is async because of file access or network access, it does not necessarily create a new thread.

Comment: the thing is, how did you call the functions? you didn't show it

Comment: I call the method foo using:
```Task.Run(() => foo());```
I have code stating that it is missing a ```await``` keyword further down in the function (it is calling a function wich is calling a function giving this warning) I wasn't aware that this might be a problem. How would one fix that in a function that either: doesn't need the ```await``` keyword anywhere or is calling another methode wich can only be called synchronous?

Comment: The question here isn't only about `async await`. In fact, `Task.WhenAll` should run collection of `Tasks` in parallel on multiple threads. But your log doesn't confirm that they aren't running in parallel. You can try to log `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`. Also even though thread IDs might be the same it doesn't necessarily mean it didn't run in parallel

Comment: @Nautha What code is in the `//big calculation` part?  Is there any IO calls?  You mention "tables" in your question, are we to assume there are SQL calls being made in this `//big calculation` section?

Comment: @maccettura yes, there are sql calls being made.

Comment: @Nautha Show us what those SQL calls look like

Comment: @maccettura this is an example for how I write my sql statements. the IDatabaseService is using dapper https://dotnetfiddle.net/QOFKoq

Comment: If you are dealing with CPU-bound calculations, and not with I/O-bound operations, it is probably better to use the [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for) method instead of tasks and `Task.WhenAll`. You'll get a better utilization of your CPU resources this way.

Comment: @Nautha You should edit that into your question. Code should not be provided as links to an external site, except as additional context or to further illustrate a problem. You don't have to provide your exact code here, but you should provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Are you awaiting something in `RunJob()`? 
You have to use async/await throughout the method chain.

```
async Task Main()
{
    await foo();
}

public async Task foo() 
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) 
    {
        tasks.Add(this.RunJob(i));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

}

private async Task RunJob(int month) 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"starting month {month}");

    // Simulating Long running process
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    Console.WriteLine($"stopping month {month}");

}
```

This gives me the output:

starting month 0

starting month 1

starting month 2

...

stopping month 2

stopping month 8

...

Edit:

If the long running process in `RunJob()` is non-async, you can use `await Task.Run(() => { NonAsyncMethod() })` to make `RunJob()` awaitable.

```
private async Task RunJob(int month) 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"starting month {month}");

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        NonAsyncMethod();
    });

    Console.WriteLine($"stopping month {month}");

}
```

Comment: For every method? So none of the methods called can be without async await?

Comment: Yes, every method, because if one is run synchronously, all code within that method will also run synchronous.

Comment: what if a package I use doesn't have a async method implemented? Is there a way to run those methods async as well?

Comment: @Nautha Why use async/await if the method isn't awaiting anything?

Comment: @Nautha take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830397/awaiting-a-non-async-method

Comment: @ColinM because the one function that is awaiting is awaiting for other things. And as far as I got it by now to achive my goal (it all running in differnet threads) all methods need to be asnyc or I gotta use a different approach

Comment: @MartinJohansson does that make the whole funtion async or do the synchron calls inside of it also need a Task.Run

Comment: If RunJob() is calling a non-async method from an external package that is doing the long running code, wrapping it in Task.Run() enables the RunJob() method to be awaited. You just need to await Task.Run() within RunJob().

Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the method RunJob to:

```
    private async Task RunJob(int month) {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"starting month {month}");


            //big calculation


            Console.WriteLine($"stopping month {month}");
        });
}
```

Also you should rename it to RunJob**Async**

Comment: Why method should be renamed?) It is your personal preference in regards to naming

Comment: It's not a personal preference, it is a convention, but I agree, it doesn't *have* to be renamed and many people have stopped adding `Async` to the name nowadays as it's evident if the return type is `Task`

Comment: @ColinM each developer/team sets its own conventions. If all your methods return `Task` I don't see a reason to add `Async` suffix.

Comment: @OlegI it was a Microsoft convention and pretty much everyone sticks to it.  Arguing naming conventions is silly when this answer is wrong for a way bigger reason

Comment: [Official guidelines for naming asynchronous methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types)